# Memory Leak when running: [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request]

Tags: objective-c, memory, memory-leaks, game-center, copywithzone

I'm testing my Objective C project for memory leaks using xCode Instruments tool.

The following lines (in my procedure to find matches in Game Center) are generating a Memory Leak:

```
GKMatchRequest *request = [[GKMatchRequest alloc] init];
request.minPlayers = minPlayers;
request.maxPlayers = maxPlayers;
GKMatchmakerViewController *mmvc = [[GKMatchmakerViewController alloc] initWithMatchRequest:request];
```

According to the Instruments Stack Trace, the Leaked Object is "GKMatchRequest".

Responsible Library: GameCenterFoundation

Responsible Frame: -[GKMatchRequest copyWithZone:]

[image: Instruments Tool - Memory Leaks]

I'm using ARC, so it should not be required to include 'Autorelease' right after the 'request' as suggested in some forums reporting a similar issue (i.e.:   https://forums.coronalabs.com/topic/59315-ios-native-plugin-objective-c-memory-leak/).

How to avoid this memory leak in my code ?